# &gt and &lt instead of > and < in case of XmlWriter.writeElementString

Tags: c#, xml

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("books.xml")) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("book"); 
    writer.WriteAttributeString("author", "j.k.rowling"); 
    writer.WriteAttributeString("mailBody", mail.BodyText);
    writer.WriteString("99");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

I have the above case . everything is fine but `writer.WriteAttributeString("mailBody", mail.BodyText);` gives a problem. The `mail.BodyText` is a string and has < and > in the content. When xml is written on to the file I see &gt and &lt instead . I do not want this encrypter version. How do I solve it?

Comment: This is not encrypter, this is xml specification. Characters like `< > &` are special characters in xml and must be escaped. Xml deserializer should be able to handle it properly.

Comment: You shouldn't, because something like `<book mailBody="bla<bla" />` is not a valid xml.

Comment: There is nothing to solve.  This is correct behavior.

Comment: See: [Predefined entities in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

Comment: Keep in mind that when you read the data from the XML file again using any XML reader you get the original `<`, `>` and `&` characters back.

Comment: Do you meant `BodyText` contains actual XML that you want to output as XML?

Comment: See also [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition) §2.4 Character Data and Markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax): *The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&amp;" and "&lt;" respectively.*  This is what you are seeing, and it is correct.

Comment: You can use `WriteRaw` to write string.This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an "encrypted version", it's a standard-compliant one. XML prohibits `<` in attributes; you must use its corresponding character entity instead.

This is the correct behavior: when you read the attribute back from that XML file, the `string` that you get back from the `mailBody` attribute would have the original characters in place of character entities, so the data would "round-trip" correctly.

If you would like a section that displays `<` and `>` in the raw XML form, use `CDATA` section instead:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("mailBody");
writer.WriteCData(mail.BodyText);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I get ![CDATA[] in the xml, is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: @Goodie Why? You can't embed `<` and `>` in _valid_ XML text or attributes.  If you want to generate invalid XML you'll have to generate the XML as a string instead of using an `XmlWriter`, since it keeps you from doing things that would result in invalid XML. Note that you also wouldn't be able to use a stanrdad XML _reader_ to read the invalid XML.

Comment: @Goodie You can't get rid of `CDATA`  markup around your `CDATA` section. In a valid XML you'll either have `CDATA` around the text, or `&lt;` inside the text.

Comment: @Goodie what are you going to do with that xml after all? Read it? It's mainly for consumption by machines, not by humans.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a solution for future references.

To generate `<` and `>` characters instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, you need to use the `WriteRaw()` method.

Here is the implementation,

```
w.WriteStartElement("myRoot");
w.WriteRaw("<");
w.WriteEndElement();
```

**Output**

```
<myRoot><</myRoot>
```

Hope this helps. Thank you!

[Solution Credits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zhk8s1x(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: And now you've generated invalid XML. How is that helpful?

Comment: Well, I am using XML to import data to my database tables. This invalid XML works for me. I do not have to publish it anywhere.

Comment: This is helpful when I need to insert a raw xml string into the xml writer as valid xml instead of a string. Yes, it does allow invalid xml to be generated, but if you insert valid xml into the 'WriteRaw' statement it does the trick.